# async and callback comprehension and naming convention

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asynchronous

I'm using ASIHTTPRequest in my application, exclusively with asynchronous request.
Some methods are composite of asynchronous methods.
For instance, look at some method +(void)updateData, it will call

- [x downloadData1] wich is asynchronous
- [y downloadData2] wich is asynchronous
- ...

Because of asynchronous/callback mecanism, my method updateData will be split (instead of only one method in a synchronous context), it will need :

```
-(void) updateData {
    ... // Some work
    x.callback = @selector(updateData1);
    [x downloadData1];
}


-(void) updateData1 {
    ... // Some work
    y.callback = @selector(updateData2);
    [x downloadData2];
}

...

- (void) updateDataN {
    ... // Some work
    // Need to callback my own "delegate"
    [self.target performSelector:callback ...];
}
```

Therefore, updateData is also asynchronous.

This code doesn't come from my project, I just tried to depict a simple example. But there can be some conditionnal calls and composite of composite...

And here it comes, the code becomes hardly readable. It is hard to follow the execution flow.
What good practice or naming convention do you advise to notify that a method is asynchronous (the -Async suffix ?) or for callback ? I find the suffix with number ugly, and not appropriate for non-linear flow.

What do you recommand ? and what did you came across ?
Or maybe do you think it results from poor designed code ?

Comment: Have you thought of using something like NSOperation to create more modular requests? It can get messy if you dump it all in one class, but if you separate each request in a different class it becomes much more readable. NSOperation provides a nice queuing system but it shouldn't be hard to create your own too.(http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

Refactor it to use blocks - that would put the response right next to the request?